# Construct relatively prime pairs from set of nonrelatively prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers

Is it possible? Given a set of numbers S such that every possible combination of the numbers in S are nonrelatively prime, can you construct a pair of relatively prime numbers by adding up arbitrary combinations of the numbers from S?

Comment: can you give an example of such a set $S$?

Comment: Such as (6,9,15), they are not relatively prime to each other.

Comment: Ah, of course! Sets, it must be *set theory*! Coincidentally this argument never goes through to [number-theory], although in this case it's much closer to number theory than it is to set theory.

Comment: Sorry, new user and had no idea what to tag the question with since I didn't find prime or coprime tags.

Comment: [prime-numbers]?

Comment: Ah, missed that somehow. Thanks!

Comment: @Jin, make your life slightly easier then and consider the set {3,6}. Can you construct relatively prime numbers by adding things up from this set?

Comment: My intuition tells me no, but I can't think of a formal way to generalize the fact to all sets that satisfy the condition.

Comment: any number which is obtained by adding things from {3,6} must be of the form 3*m+6*k. This is a multiple of 3.

Comment: It might be interesting to consider $S=\{pq,pr,qr\}$ for distinct primes $p,q,r$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a number $d\gt1$ that divides every element of $S$, then it is easy to see that it will also divide every sum of elements of $S$, so, in this case, the answer is no.

If there is no such number $d$, then it is always possible to find two coprime integer linear combinations of elements of $S$.   I'll show you a way to do it if $S$ has $3$ numbers, $S=\{{a,b,c\}}$, and you can think about how to generalize.

Let $t$ be the product of all the primes that divide $c$ but not $a$. Then $\gcd(a+bt,c)=1$. For, let $p$ be a prime dividing $c$. If $p$ divides $a$, then it can't divide $b$, nor $t$, nor $bt$, nor $a+bt$. If $p$ doesn't divide $a$, then it must divide $t$, so it divides $bt$, so it doesn't divide $a+bt$.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes.  Consider $S = \{15,21,35\}$.  Each pair has a factor in common but $15+21=36$ is relatively prime to $35$.